# 3 queries in 1 action that depends on each

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have 3 queries named `$stmt9`, `$stmt10` and `$stmt11`. I need to run the query in order, e.g. run `9`, then `10`, and finally `11`. If there is something wrong, I want to rollback the queries that have been done, e.g. if the problem is on `10`, it should rollback `9`, or if on `11`, then should roll back `10` and `9`.

I have the following code, but when something is wrong, sometimes it still runs `$stmt9` only, or `$stmt9` and `$stmt10` but not `$stmt11`.

How to fix it?

This is the update action:

```
$this->conn->beginTransaction();    
    $stmt9 = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE tableONE SET condition= :condition WHERE `tb1_id`= :id LIMIT 1");
    condition
    $id = Check_Get_Param($_GET['id']); 
    $stmt9->bindParam(':condition' , $this->condition);
    $stmt9->bindParam(':id' , $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt9->execute();

    $stmt10 = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE tableTOW SET disterbute = :dis WHERE tb2_id = :tbl2id LIMIT 1");
    $stmt10->bindParam(":counting", $this->counting, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt10->bindParam(":tbl2id ", $this->tbl2id , PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt10->execute();

    $stmt11 = $this->conn->prepare("DELETE FROM tableTHREE WHERE tb3_id = :id limit 1");
    $stmt11->bindParam(":id",$id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt11->execute();

        if($stmt9 && $stmt10 && $stmt11){
            $this->conn->commit(); //This will save my changes
            header('location:../success.php');
            exit;
        } else {
            $this->conn->rollBack(); //This will undo your changes 
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0">'. $message;      
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you've already ensure that your table is created on InnoDB (or other storage driver) that supports transaction, not MyISAM which didn't.

Comment: One more thing, the two UPDATE and one DELETE statement can always work. The condition can results in zero (0) affected records and the execute() returns true (not checking the statement, but the return value of $stmtXX->execute().

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a transaction.
I checked and it is implemented in pdo.

Example taken from the documentation:

```
<?php
/* Begin a transaction, turning off autocommit */
$dbh->beginTransaction();

/* Change the database schema and data */
$sth = $dbh->exec("DROP TABLE fruit");
$sth = $dbh->exec("UPDATE dessert
    SET name = 'hamburger'");

/* Recognize mistake and roll back changes */
$dbh->rollBack();

/* Database connection is now back in autocommit mode */
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php

Comment: YES here as you see on my question i have implemented but it's not working even if there is any error on first statment it's runing the last statment.

Comment: @abas_rafiq that's because **you** need to check for errors when you want to rollBack, and currently you make no real checks at all...